# How to check what command is taken?

Tags: command-line, paths, execute-command

I have a shell script called `foo.sh` in `/usr/local/sbin`. Besides I use another script with the same name. It is stored in `/home/user/scripts`.

Both paths belong to `PATH`. How can I find out, which one of those scripts are executed when typing `foo.sh` on the command line? Can I influence it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few days ago I was satisfied with my answer. I also knew that the `which` command is not used to test whether a command exists. Now I'm not so satisfied with my answer, and I refer to this [great response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/107084).

---

With a simple `which` command:

```
which foo.sh
```

Or a `type` command:

```
type foo.sh
```

And you can influence this with the order of the paths in your `$PATH` or via an absolute path when the script starts, E.G.

```
/home/user/scripts/foo.sh
```

---

*Example*

If PATH is defined as below

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

And you start a script or something else which is in `/usr/local/bin` and in `/usr/bin`, the script in `/usr/local/bin` as  a higher priority.

Comment: Speaking of `bash` and `zsh` there's also the `type` built-in; instead in `zsh` `which`, differently from `bash`, is a built-in (and not `/usr/bin/which`)

Comment: [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/70524)

Comment: @muru thanks. A little I knew about it already, but not in such detail. I've added my views to my answer. Thanks again.